# In PhpStorm opening “Find in path” dialog use hot keys for my custom scopes

Tags: phpstorm

If there is a way in PhpStorm 2019.2.3 opening “Find in path” dialog to select my custom scopes
created priorly by some hot key? Or to move these custom scopes at top of all scopes?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such functionality (to bring that popup with predefined scope selected). IDE remembers selected scope/option from previous invocation (as long as you invoke it from the Editor). Although it may forget it after you close the project (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143972). P.S. You can write your own plugin though to do that: right now if you invoke it from a Project View when directory is focused, IDE will choose "Directory" and select that directory in the path field. Which suggests that it's possible to select "Scope" and preselect desired scope this way...

Comment: P.P.S. PhpStorm supports IDE scripting -- you may be able to achieve that without writing the plugin... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.1/ide-scripting-console.html. Some samples: https://gist.github.com/gregsh/b7ef2e4ebbc4c4c11ee9

Comment: Thanks! But that seems too complicated. Have anybody make such plugin? If yes please share

Comment: Check here (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/phpStorm) or "Settings/Preferences | Plugins". I never had a need for such specific functionality (can select a folder or scope when needed; + my searches affect whole project) and cannot say if such plugin exists already or not.